# iOS - Trigger notification when new data is posted to NSMutableArray?

Tags: ios, mysql, objective-c, push-notification

I've setup push notifications on my server, and everything works great. **E.g.** I can send a notification to all users (as all device tokens are stored to my database) at anytime. That said, I want to send a push notification to a device when the data on the server which is mirrored in the app is updated (***e.g.*** when a new message is posted to the server)?

***More specifically:*** See below the code that I use to display all received messages in a tableview. How do I make it so that the logged in user receives a notification when, say, self.messages is updated?

**ViewController.m**

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *PointsTableIdentifier = @"MyMessagesCell";

    MyMessagesCell *cell = (MyMessagesCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:PointsTableIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyMessagesCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell = [nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }


    NSDictionary *receivedSubjectLine = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *messageSubject = [receivedSubjectLine objectForKey:@"node_title"];


    [cell.subjectLine setText:messageSubject];



    NSDictionary *fromUser = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *userName = [fromUser objectForKey:@"name"];

    [cell.senderName setText:userName];



    NSDictionary *receivedBody = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *messageBody = [receivedBody objectForKey:@"body"];

    [cell.fullMessage setText:messageBody];


    NSDictionary *receivedTime = [self.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    NSString *timeStamp = [receivedTime objectForKey:@"swaptime"];

        NSLog(@"The timestamp is %@", timeStamp);

    [cell.swapTime setText:timeStamp];

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: You just need to write the code you need at the point where you update the array.

Comment: Why would you send a notification to the app when the app itself updates? That absolutely makes no sense whatsoever. If actually you want to send a push to another device when the app  updates, or to send a push to a device when the data on a server which is mirrored in the app is updated, then both of these make sense but that is not what your question asks.

Comment: @SausageModulationMatrix Sorry, that's what I meant: I want to send a push notification to a device when the data on the server which is mirrored in the app is updated. How might I go about doing this?

Comment: @Paulw11 Yes, but what IS that code? I can't seem to find documentation for executing it anywhere.

Comment: Normally your server would do this; your app updates the server and the server notifies the clients

Answer (score 0):

I have a chat in my App that doesn't use Web Socket (we have not has the time to implemented it), so what we do is to refresh the UITableView using the notification center.

In the AppDelegate I have this code:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadTheTable" object:nil];
}
```

And then in my chat class I have this code to register the notification in the viewDidLoad:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(reloadTable:) name:@"reloadTheTable" object:nil];
```

And then the selector calls the server and refresh the data displayed:

```
- (void)reloadTable:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
    [self checkJson]; //This function loads the data and when it finish calls another method call loadTable
}

- (void)loadTable {
    [_tvTable reloadData]; //this simply reload your UITableView
}
```

I have also use this technic to reload when the App come to foreground:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application
{
    // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadTheTable" object:nil];
}
```

I hope this helps you.

Comment: I don't understand - how would the above send a push notification to my user's device when new data is posted?

Comment: @BBL18 As far I understand your question, you want that when the server database is updated your device will receive a Push and then you need to update the data on the device, so when your Server updates the database you have to call your send push method in your server and with my code you will receive the push and send a notification to the system, that will update your table.